# How to center one of the child widget out of 2 child widgets

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently, I have a `LinearLayout` with `NumberPicker` & `TextView` (With text "long string string")

[image]

This is not something I wish to achieve. What I wish to achieve is

1. `NumberPicker` will be at horizontal center
2. "long string string" `TextView` will just sit nicely at the right side of `NumberPicker`

The following layout won't work. As it treats `NumberPicker` + `TextView` as single element, and center horizontal both of them together.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text_view"
        android:text="@string/might_drain_battery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/number_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="long string string"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I change the code slightly. I remove `gravity` from inner `LinearLayout`, and place `layout_gravity` in `NumberPicker`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="long string string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But, that won't work still (I was wondering why `NumberPicker` no longer in center)

[image]

Any suggestion how can I achieve my desired layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a LinearLayout for that.

A RelativeLayout allows the attribute `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for its children (so the NumberPicker is placed) or even `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` (if the alignment has to be also vertical).

It also allows the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameOfAnotherControl"` for a child which wants to be placed at the right of another control (and so the TextView is also placed).

And that's all

This would be your (slightly) modified layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="long string string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/number_picker"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: I replaced "Linear" with "Relative" and added an attribute to both the controls.
Now the NumberPicker is relative to the parent and the TextView is relative to the NumberPicker AND the parent.
I also added an extra attribute to the TextView, to center it vertically.